# Old -versus- New- Mobile Home that should carry Homeowners insurance?

Tags: florida, home-insurance

A brand new mobile home was put on 4 acres that I own and there is another much older mobile home on the property, which one should carry "Homeowners insurance?

Comment: Do you own both mobile homes?  Can you explain further exactly what you are asking?

Answer (score 2):

Talk to your insurance agent.  You at least want liability insurance for the whole property. If there is a loan against either of the mobiles, the bank will insist you insure it; ask them what their requirements are.

If there's no loan,  And no local legal requirement -- which the agent should be able to tell you -- this becomes like the question of whether you need comprehensive insurance on a car. Do you care if a disaster destroys it completely or do you want some protection against that? Price it both ways; you may find that leaving one "naked" doesn't save as much as you expect.